# How to make some class not affect inside a class

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

So I have a menu with a drop down like this:

http://slypaste.org/KmsRuS4k

Sorry for the links, I just never have luck with stackoverflow html system..

So the drop down menu has the same style as the buttons which look ugly on drop downs.
I've tried adding a class to its li style and it still ignroed it

this is what makes the hover colors & bg of the drop down:

http://slypaste.org/5Kxv43WS

I've tried everything I know but still doesn't work.

Aim:

Make the menu drop down color and links look completely different from the other menus.

Live demo:

http://justxp.plutohost.net/testing/index.html

as you see, basically it takes the border from the menu class.

Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: Ah now I understand what you mean. You have the dropdown links pulling styles from the actual dropdown button; try creating a new class for the links.

Comment: What do you mean? like creating LI classes for each ? ive tried this, doesnt work. if u mean create new classes for drop down, I can't because its positioned in boostrap framework :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like jzacharia suggested in the comments above:

**CSS**

In your CSS file, change this:

```
.menu a
{
    ....
}

.menu a:hover
{
    ....
}
```

to this:

```
.menu a.title
{
    ....
}

.menu a.title:hover
{
    ....
}
```

**HTML**

And your HTML should then look something like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current"><span style="color:#bde2e1;">Home</li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle title">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="hovering"><a href="#" class="title">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="hovering"><a href="#" class="title">Releases</a></li>
    <li class="hovering"><a href="#" class="title">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey thanks that worked but a few errors:

As you can see in this image, when opening menu, theres a little border over it (ignore the black places, i just selected it so u see that some borders are visible, ive tried removing the borders from the classes but it still has 1px border.
http://gyazo.com/8e01635db9c2240cec876a8c270ee7e4


Also, when hovering the other menu links, nothing happens.

Comment: To fix the problem with the visible border, you just need to remove `z-index:5;` from `.menu li`. And what do you mean when you hover over the other menu links, nothing happens? Did you add the class `.title` to all your anchor tags? Could you maybe update your link in your original question with the updated CSS?

Comment: Well I added the classes you told me to change & styled them and hover doesn't really works.

Comment: The problem might be that you have two curly brackets after `.menu a.title`. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Fixed but when hovering a blue line comes up and disappears?

Comment: Solved, it was the border i forgot to add to make a balance so it doesn't jump on hover, I just made the border to have the same color has the header so it won't be visible, thanks man it all worked!

Answer (score 0):

.dropdown-menu a {
        background: none;
    }

```
.dropdown-menu{
    background-color: to what you want!
    padding:none;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
    color: to what you want!
}

.menu a {
    border-radius:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

That should get you started?